# Update npm module, but showing different older version in my console window

Tags: node.js, socket.io, npm

I wanted to install the latest version of socket.io, and the latest ver seems to be 1.45.[socket.io download](http://socket.io/download/)

To do this, I just type the following command.

`npm install socket.io`

However, when I checked installed modules in my laptop, socket.io's version did not change as can be seen below.

`YANAGISAWAYUMA-no-MacBook-Pro:~ yanagisawa_yuma$ npm list --depth=0
yanagisawa_yuma@0.0.0 /Users/yanagisawa_yuma
├── ar-drone@0.3.3 extraneous (git://github.com/felixge/node-ar-drone.git#228bd4573e765bed3861f259ce7e66fcace15f43)
├── express@4.9.0
├── gulp@3.9.0
├── node@0.0.0
├── node-osc@1.1.0 extraneous
├── node-static@0.7.3
├── socket.io@1.1.0
└── static@2.0.0`

What am I missing?

Comment: Try `npm install socket.io@latest`

Comment: now latest version is installed.
however, got the error
```
npm ERR! invalid: socket.io@1.4.5 /Users/yanagisawa_yuma/node_modules/socket.io
```

Is this a different thing?

Comment: Have you checked your package.json??
change version there and do npm update

Comment: What `node` and `npm` version?

Comment: @NitishAgarwal You are right. I had a package.json, whose dependencies decided socket.io's version.. Now, just removed the json file, and got no errors. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of simply npm install socket.io,
try npm install socket.io@version

Comment: You are right. I had a package.json, whose dependencies decided socket.io's version..
Now, just removed the json file, and got no errors.
Thank you very much!

Comment: @YumaYanagisawa, comment about package.json is by Nitish not me.

Comment: oh... I was messed up.